# Iterate JSON response from API using AngularJS ngResponse

Tags: javascript, json, api, angularjs

I'm taking my first steps with AngularJS calling an API that would send back a JSON object with the data that I need.  I calls the API and takes the response and print it on the HTML, iterating as needed.

But I haven't found a way on the actual Javascript file, to iterate to lets say, group and sum items, or to print the actual values of the JSON to the console.

**app.js**

```
    angular.module('dashboard', ['ngResource']);
    function DashboardCtrl($scope, $resource) {
        $scope.dailyReports = $resource('http://myurl.com/app_dev.php/:action',
            {action:'dailyreports', appid:'@appid', begindate:'@begindate', enddate:'@enddate'});


    $scope.loadData = function() {
            $scope.dailyreportsResults = $scope.dailyReports.get({appid:$('#sel-apps').val(), begindate:$('#fecha-inicial').val(), enddate:$('#fecha-final').val()});
//it works!!!!
        };

$scope.iterate = function() {

            for (i=0; i < $scope.dailyreportsResults.data.length; i++){
                    $scope.periodUnits += $scope.dailyreportsResults.data[i].units;
                    console.log($scope.periodUnits);
                    //It doesnt work :(

            }
    };
```

**index.html**

```
ng-repeat="data in dailyreportsResults.data"
   {{data.countryName}}
   {{data.units}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Just WHEN are you calling `$scope.iterate`? The ng-repeat directive will work after the JSON's been loaded, but calling iterate before the data is received will result in an error, or nothing at all! Try using the $resource callbacks - `$scope.dailyReports.get({YOURDATA}, function(){callback -call iterate()})`

Comment: I agree, I don't see where you call the iterate function from. Can you create a JSFiddle for us with this error in it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your data looks like, but maybe you should be using 'for in' instead of incrementing an array.

```
$scope.iterate = function() {
  for (x in $scope.dailyreportsResults.data){
    $scope.periodUnits += $scope.dailyreportsResults.data[x].units;
    console.log($scope.periodUnits);
  }
};
```

also, I think your ng-repeat should be attached to an element.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dailyreportsResults.data">
   {{data.countryName}}
   {{data.units}}
</div>
```